# htaccess redirect specific URL to different domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have 2 domain pointing to same directory, Now I want to redirect some URLs to one specific domain and rest should be on main domain.

I have one domain www.xyz.com this is main domain site will be open with this domain, from this domain I want to redirect specific URLs to different domain so if someone open www.xyz.com/a/theatre then it should redirect to www.abc.com/a/theatre. And now from same this new domain if someone click on URL which don't have "/a/theatre" in URL then it should redirect back to main domain. So if someone open **www.abc.com/a/classes** then it should redirect to **www.xyz.com/a/classes**

I have used bellow rules but not working,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.xyz.com$ [NC]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/a/theatre$    
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.abc.com/a/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com$ [NC]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/a/theatre    
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.xyz.com/a/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Here is all code from my htaccess, I have installed Joomla on this domain.

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /seo
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mcleancenter.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/seo/alden-theatre$
RewriteRule ^/?seo/(.*)$ http://www.aldentheatre.org/seo/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.aldentheatre.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/seo/alden-theatre
RewriteRule ^/?seo/(.*)$ http://www.mcleancenter.org/seo/$1 [NC,L,R=301]

########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to match out the leading `/a/` by adding a `^/?a/` to the front of the regex in the rules.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.xyz.com$ [NC]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/a/theatre$    
RewriteRule ^/?a/(.*)$ http://www.abc.com/a/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com$ [NC]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/a/theatre    
RewriteRule ^/?a/(.*)$ http://www.xyz.com/a/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Jon. I have added ^/?a/ in both rules, but then both are not working.

Comment: @AmbrishDave are these rules in an htaccess file that is not in the document root?

Comment: This is in htaccess file and this file is in "a" folder.

Comment: @AmbrishDave then no idea what you're doing wrong, WHen I put your rules in a blank htaccess file in a directory called `/a`, everything works just fine.

Comment: @AmbrishDave you don't need the `/?seo/` in the rules if this file is in a directory called `/seo` Other than that, they work fine for me.

Comment: so I need to add (.*)$ instead of ^/?seo/(.*)$ in both rules?

Comment: @AmbrishDave yeah, make them `^(.*)$`

Comment: I have added ^(.*)$, but 1st rule not working. It is not redirecting www.mcleancenter.org/seo/alden-theatre to www.aldentheatre.org/seo/alden-theatre

Comment: Hi Jon Lin, any suggestion? any help?

Comment: @AmbrishDave don't know what's wrong, it all works fine for me.